# read cookies on a non web c# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I wrote a website

I want to write cookies manager who will read cookies.

Can I reside it in a non web-page project?

I develop with ASP.NET

```
if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
{
    string userSettings;
    if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"] != null)
    { userSettings = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"]; }
}
```

but after adding system.web

Request.Cookies

cannot be resolved

Comment: Please supply the code you are using.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I reside it in a non web-page project?

Yes, you simply need to reference the appropriate assemblies (System.Web) in your non-web project.

Comment: still Request.Cookies cannot be resoved

Comment: Because it needs to be `HttpContext.Request.Cookies`

Comment: While this easily could have been a comment, because the author supplied no code, this is the best and pretty much only answer possible.

Comment: I now get error: cannot access non-static property 'Request' in a static context

Comment: @EladBenda Are you passing a reference of the HttpRequest to your static method?